# Archivo con datos de conexión a API Rest en React JS

Tags: javascript, api, reactjs

Estoy creando un proyecto con `ReactJS` y estoy tratando de crear un componente que hace `login` buscando el usuario en una `API`.

Me gustaría que los datos de dicha `API` se almacenaran en un archivo `js` distinto y que el componente de `login` llame a este archivo para extraer los datos, de modo que cada componente que haga una llamada a la `API`, use la variable que contiene los datos de conexión para que de este modo, si debo realizar algún cambio en la conexión, solo deba cambiar un archivo y no todas las funciones.

El ejemplo de como estoy tratando de realizar dicho archivo lo veis a continuación:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Conexion extends Component {

  render(){
    return{

        datosConexion : {
            "servidor" : 'IP y puerto',
            "instancia" : 'instancia',
            "proyecto_de_datos" : ' proyecto de datos',
            "nombre_tabla" : 'nombre tabla',
            "nombre_tabla_hist" : 'nombre tabla',
            "api_key" : 'api key'
        }

     }
  }
}

export default Conexion;
```

Comment: ¿Por que habrías de crear un componente? Simplemente exporta el objeto `datosConexion` e importa este en el componente `login`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesitas crear un componente para el problema que propones, solo necesitas exportar el objecto con los datos de la API, despues importarlo en todos aquellos componentes que lo necesites.

conexion.js:

`export let datosConexion = {
            "servidor" : 'IP y puerto',
            "instancia" : 'instancia',
            "proyecto_de_datos" : ' proyecto de datos',
            "nombre_tabla" : 'nombre tabla',
            "nombre_tabla_hist" : 'nombre tabla',
            "api_key" : 'api key'
        }`

Luego en el componente donde deseas utilizarlo añades la linea:

```
import { datosConexion } from './conexion'
```

De este modo tendrás acceso a todos los datos que contenga el objeto datosConexion.